# How to convert CDX spread to price?

Tags: finance, derivatives, credit

Example: assume the current HY CDX is with 5% coupon. The spread is around 300bps, with a duration of around 4 years.

Would you pls help me to understand why we can proxy the HY CDX price as
100+4*(5%-3%)=100+duration*(coupon-spread)=108
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This "proxy" is too approximate, but is an OK first approximation. (By the way, CDX HY is "officially" quoted as price, not as spread.)

You need to run the [ISDA CDS standard model](https://www.cdsmodel.com/cdsmodel/). You can actually download an Excel add-in, but it would be a more useful exercise for you compile the C++ code. Then you you'll have the "official" conversion between the market standard quote spread and the upfront. Rememeber to use interest rate curves from the right historical date.

IHS Maikit provides a [converter](https://www.markit.com/converter.jsp) web page. You can plug in your spread and get the index price. Read the ISDA documentation to understand how it works.

Comment: would you pls help me understand why this approximation makes sense?@dimitri Vulis

Comment: Think of the quoted spread as the annual cost of protection if the upfront fee was 0. But practically, CDX IG index trades with 500 bps running coupon a year. Ignoring convexity, "spread 01" is the change in the upfront fee from 1 basis point change in the spread - think of this sensitivity, rather than unintuitive duration. Right now the HY series 36 index price is around 109.8% corresponding to spread around 280 bps - much less than 500, which is why the index price is above par. Conversely, if the price went below par, then the spread would go above 500.